# Configure the code snippet using Registry

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I have HTML Code snippets. I need to configure it in customer machine while install the setup. I am using below registry entry to configure the code snippets in VS 2010.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\CodeExpansions\HTML
```

I have added the snippet location in “Path” Name in the above location. It is working fine if we used snippets in that machine before install the Setup. But it is not working in fresh machine. In fresh machine the “Path” entry is not available. 
Please help me to register the code snippet in fresh machine.

Comment: Sure it won't be available, you have to *add* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this. If we add the entries in below registry location the Snippet will be available in fresh machine.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Languages\CodeExpansions\HTML\Paths
```

Add string value and put the Snippet path location as data value under the above location.